# No column information was returned by the SQL command. SSDT

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2017

I'm attempting to create an update query in SSDT. I'm getting

> Unable to parse query text.

The query is:

```
UPDATE CustOrderWithDisp
SET YARDS = CustOrderWithDisp.QUANTITY * Lkp_TestCodes.[Test_GALS] * 0.00495113
FROM CustOrderWithDisp
INNER JOIN Lkp_TestCodes
ON CustOrderWithDisp.TEST_CODE = Lkp_TestCodes.[SVC CODE]
```

But if I actually run the query, it works.

I want to use this query in an SSIS package. When I put this query in an OLEDB Source, i get...

The component reported the following warnings:

> Error at qry03_CalculateYards [OLE DB Source [33]]: No column information was returned by the SQL command.

I'm a novice at this, so be gentle. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you trying to use an UPDATE command as a OLEDB Source?   What are you trying to do?

Comment: I’m just trying to learn the program and there’s absolutely no tutorials for this. Learning on the fly. But I see what the issue was with Hadi’s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error at qry03_CalculateYards [OLE DB Source [33]]: No column information was returned by the SQL command.

You are receiving this message because `OLEDB Source` is a `DataFlow Task` component, it is used to read data from an  Table or SQL Command through an OLEDB Connection.

> The OLE DB source extracts data from a variety of OLE DB-compliant relational databases by using a database table, a view, or an SQL command. For example, the OLE DB source can extract data from tables in Microsoft Office Access or SQL Server databases.

You don't have to put this query in an `OLEDB Source`, **you have to use an `Execute SQL Task` and write this query in the `SQL Command` property.**

For UPDATE queries you have to use `Execute SQL Task` *(in the Control Flow level, no in the DataFlow)*

> The Execute SQL task runs SQL statements or stored procedures from a package. The task can contain either a single SQL statement or multiple SQL statements that run sequentially.

**References**

- [Execute SQL Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task)
- [OLEDB Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/ole-db-source)